# Pass or Share data across components in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to Redux, so this may be an issue with my store's design or my understanding.

I have 2 componenents in my application:

1. The Navigation component renders a list of links based on the
   response from an API call.
2. The Content component fetches the content
   for the link selected in Navigation component and renders the HTML.

Here's my hirearchy:

```
- index.js (building store here)
- actions
    - NavigationActions
    - ContentActions
- components 
    - Home 
    - Navigation
    - Content   
- containers
    - NavigationContainer
    - ContentContainer
- reducers
    - NavigationReduer (manages 'navigation' part of the store)
    - ContentReducer (manages 'content' part of the store)
    - RootReducer (combineReducers sits here)
```

I have been able to load navigation links and content (index.html) when the application loads. When a link is clicked in the Navigation component, I dispatch an action which puts a 'selectedResource' key within the "navigation" part of the store which is the selected link.

My question is how do I share the "selectedResource" with the Content component so that it loads the new resource and renders it's HTML content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ContentContainer` when you `mapStateToProps`, you will do the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ NavigationState }) => {
  return {
    selectedResource: NavigationState.selectedResource
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContentContainer);
```

To detect a change in `selectedResource` in `ContentContainer`, you could:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  //May need some different comparison logic
  if(this.props.selectedResource != prevProps.selectedResource) {
      triggerNextAction();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And what would be the best place to trigger the next action for ContentContainer component to fetch the selected resource and re-render?

Comment: Edited my answer